# Use Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK

Tags: android, broadcast

How do I use Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK correctly?
I would like to create a receiver which checks the battery-level every minute.

I use a Broadcast-receiver class witch is first started from main-Activity.
Starting the broadcast receiver is not the problem. When the app is open everything works fine. However, if the app ends, I will no longer receive broadcast information.

Now to my problem: how can I continue to receive information after completing the app?

My Sourcecode.

Start the Broadcast:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
    [...]
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String app = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        [...]
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
                Log.d(app + ".Main", "register receiver with '" + Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK + "'");
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

Receive information in Receiver.class:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        BatteryManager bm = (BatteryManager)context.getSystemService(context.BATTERY_SERVICE);
        int akku = bm.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK))
        {
            Log.d(app + ".Receiver", "Receiver detected '" + action + "'");
            if(minute%5 == 0) {
                startNotification(akku);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver"
        android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_TIME_TICK"></action>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to registre the receiver in Service, than it will work on background.
I dont know it on 100%, but I think that TIME_TICK doesnt work if you define it in manifest, you must register it in class.

Answer (score 0):

you need to register your broadcaster subclass either on subclassed applicant *onCreate() {...}* or in your activity..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the service for running in the background even after your app is closed and will notify the required.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).